# How to load CSS file with Google App Engine

Tags: php

I'm learning deploying a simple website to GAE. The problem I faced is how to load css file for my index page. As far as I read (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/staticfiles) is very easy, but my index page didn't work as what I expect to.

Here is my structure folder: 
             MyWeb(
                stylesheets( main.css),
                favicon.ico,
                main.php,
                index.html,
                app.yaml
             )
I configured my app.yaml:

```
application: DemoGAE2013
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: index.html

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
```

Finally, In index.html, I add reference:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
```

Please tell me which wrong I had in this project.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Those docs indicate you need the following in your YAML:

```
handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
```

You've told it where to find the favicon, but not the stylesheets.

Comment: Sr, I have inserted this (- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets) into yaml but I forgot put it into my answer. Although I inserted this statement in .yaml, my page doesn't work.